# How to search if a value exists in set Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'd like to know what's wrong with this code? It was working fine with the previous version of Android Studio but something may have changed with the new updates. I'd like to confirm if the checkUserExists method is correct.

```
public void loginButtonClicked(View view) {
    String email = loginEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String pass = loginPass.getText().toString().trim();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)) {
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    checkUserExists;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public void checkUserExists() {
    final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(user_id)) {
                Intent loginIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(loginIntent);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.` See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to call the method `checkUserExists` inside the `onComplete()` like this:

```
checkUserExists();
```

and not as you do now.

Second use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead of `addValueEventListener`.

Comment: I see, thanks for the help. One last thing, does the Intent need to be imported or is there a separate piece of code that declares it?

Comment: If it wasn't imported automatically, please use this line of code: `import android.content.Intent;` It works?